# Has anyone successfull run Apigee Edge as a Docker container?

Tags: docker, apigee

We're starting to go down the containerization route with Docker and have created Docker versions of some of our infrastructure and applications.

Apigee is proving a little more of a struggle...we're doing a standalone install inside our Dockerfile and that works great. Once the install has finished and the container is started you can hit the UI and the management API just fine from the machine running the container.

The problem appears to be the virtualhost. Inside the container it is fine - if you enter the container (nsenter has been massively useful) you canthe run the /test/test1-sa.sh script no problems. From outside the container that virtualhost port is not accessible, even when you use the EXPOSE command inside your Dockerfile.

The only thing I maybe have to go on is the value for all the hostname entries inside our silent installation file. It is pointing to 127.0.0.1, which the Apigee docs seem to warn against.

Many thanks
Michael

Comment: plz share the steps to run Apigee as standalone

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set your hostname to your external IP adress in /etc/hosts (as Docker runs on Ubuntu -- I believe it's in /etc/sysconfig/network if you're running CentOS). It should look something like this at a minimum:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
172.56.12.67    MyApigeeInstance
```

Then running hostname -i should give you the outside ip address and the individual compoents will know how to find each other. Otherwise all components are being registered as 127.0.0.1 and the machines can't find each other.

You might also want to take a look at what ports are open for your docker image.  The install doc for Apigee lists a TON of ports you need open for the various components.

I don't know if you have to do this as part of the docker image or if it there is a way to configure its underlying Ubuntu settings.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a go tomorrow. Presumably the value for MyApigeeInstance is what you put in your silent installation file? I presume that this would also make that Dockerfile non-portable, or would you edit the /etc/hosts (or Centos equivalent) each time you started the container? Many thanks

Comment: You would edit your /etc/hosts file -- MyApigeeInstance might have been a bad example, it's just your hostname. As long as your linux installation is set up to read hostname -i and return the real IP address (as opposed to localhost) Apigee should read that IP and report it to Zookeeper (the central repository for Apigee components)